# How to get Instrumentation object from outside tests

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator, android-instrumentation

I need to test my UI on android using UiAutomation and UiDevice which I get from Instrumentation. To get the Instrumentation object from testing area, I just add *testInstrumentationRunner* in my .gradle file and get the object from

`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()`

However when I call the above method from my activity class, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.

I have tried registering instrumentation in my *AndroidManifest* file, but the error persists. Also in the instrumentation tag targetPackage does not recognize my package and shows in red:

[image: instrumentation tag]

How can I get the Instrumentation object from outside the testing class?

Comment: "How can I get the Instrumentation object from outside the testing class?" -- why do you need this? What specifically are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: @CommonsWare this is for work. I have an android phone connected to my PC, that will send testing instructions to the phone and the phone should reply back to the PC with the result. The PC-Android communication is done via my service and because of it, I need that service to be able to launch custom tests that use Instrumentation as a reference object to get UiAutomation, UiDevice, Intent and Context.

Comment: Either you are developing an Android app (and have no access to `Instrumentation`, `UiAutomation`, and kin) or you are developing an instrumentation test suite. In the latter case, presumably you could rig up some sort of socket-based means for the PC to drive the testing process, though this is well outside the scope of conventional Android testing. However, that socket would not be in an Android service, but rather in some test-related class (custom test runner, perhaps).

Comment: @CommonsWare So you are saying that there is no access to 'Instrumntation' from within the app? I use Tcp server-client type connection and already have asynchronous massaging between them set up. I don't need the app specifically, so I guess I will try to establish the PC-Android connection through the testing suite and run the tests from it.

Comment: "So you are saying that there is no access to 'Instrumntation' from within the app?" -- if it is being run as part of an instrumentation test, perhaps. But not if it is running as an ordinary Android app, for obvious privacy and security reasons.